# Adding elements to hierarchy for circle packing colours

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to set a specific colour of my circles using the circle packing example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269#index.html) based on an number in my data. However when I use:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color });
```

with the data:

```
var classes = [
    { id: '1', value: 1, color: '#42f445' },
    { id: '2', value: 2, color: '#f44141' },
    { id: '3', value: 3, color: '#42f445' },
    { id: '4', value: 4, color: '#f44141' },
    { id: '5', value: 5, color: '#42f445' },
    { id: '6', value: 6, color: '#f44141' },
    { id: '7', value: 7, color: '#42f445' }
];
```

and the root:

```
var root = d3.hierarchy({ children: classes })
    .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .each(function(d) {
        if (id = d.data.id) {
            var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
            d.id = id;
            d.package = id.slice(0, i);
            d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
        }
    });
```

It just shows the circles all black?

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be `d.data.color`, not `d.color`:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.data.color });
```

Check this demo with your code (ignore the first `undefined`, that's the root itself):

```js
var classes = [{
  id: '1',
  value: 1,
  color: '#42f445'
}, {
  id: '2',
  value: 2,
  color: '#f44141'
}, {
  id: '3',
  value: 3,
  color: '#42f445'
}, {
  id: '4',
  value: 4,
  color: '#f44141'
}, {
  id: '5',
  value: 5,
  color: '#42f445'
}, {
  id: '6',
  value: 6,
  color: '#f44141'
}, {
  id: '7',
  value: 7,
  color: '#42f445'
}];

var root = d3.hierarchy({
    children: classes
  })
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .each(function(d) {
    if (id = d.data.id) {
      var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
      d.id = id;
      d.package = id.slice(0, i);
      d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
    }
  });

root.each(function(d) {
  console.log(d.data.color)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now look what happens if you use just `d.data`, as you did:

```js
var classes = [{
  id: '1',
  value: 1,
  color: '#42f445'
}, {
  id: '2',
  value: 2,
  color: '#f44141'
}, {
  id: '3',
  value: 3,
  color: '#42f445'
}, {
  id: '4',
  value: 4,
  color: '#f44141'
}, {
  id: '5',
  value: 5,
  color: '#42f445'
}, {
  id: '6',
  value: 6,
  color: '#f44141'
}, {
  id: '7',
  value: 7,
  color: '#42f445'
}];

var root = d3.hierarchy({
    children: classes
  })
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .each(function(d) {
    if (id = d.data.id) {
      var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
      d.id = id;
      d.package = id.slice(0, i);
      d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
    }
  });

root.each(function(d) {
  console.log(d.color)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```